# Check fields and use segue on button click Xamarin iOS (C#)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm want check fields type "UITextField" if they Null or Empty. But when I'm cliсk on my button my app turn to another ViewController if fields is Null or Empty.

My code:

```
    partial class OformlenieViewController : UIViewController
{
    public string house;
    public string kvart;
    public string street;
    public string FIO;
    public string code;
    public string telephone;
    public string comment;
    public OformlenieViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {

}
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    ScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF (320, 883);
    ScrollView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
    ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;

    View.AddSubview (ScrollView);

    ulitsa.ShouldReturn = delegate {
        ulitsa.ResignFirstResponder ();
        return true;
    };

    kvartira.ShouldReturn = delegate {
        kvartira.ResignFirstResponder ();
        return true;
    };

    dom.ShouldReturn = delegate {
        dom.ResignFirstResponder ();
        return true;
    };

    fio.ShouldReturn = delegate {
        fio.ResignFirstResponder ();
        return true;
    };

    kod.ShouldReturn = delegate {
        kod.ResignFirstResponder ();
        return true;
    };

    tel.ShouldReturn = delegate {
        tel.ResignFirstResponder ();
        return true;
    };

    coment.ShouldReturn = delegate {
        coment.ResignFirstResponder ();
        return true;
    };

    send_zakaz.TouchUpInside += delegate {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (ulitsa.Text)) {
            BTProgressHUD.ShowToast ("Заполните поле 'Улица'  ", showToastCentered: false, timeoutMs: 1000);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (dom.Text)) {

            BTProgressHUD.ShowToast ("Заполните поле 'Дом'  ", showToastCentered: false, timeoutMs: 1000);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (kvartira.Text)) {
            BTProgressHUD.ShowToast ("Заполните поле 'Квартира'  ", showToastCentered: false, timeoutMs: 1000);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (fio.Text)) {
            BTProgressHUD.ShowToast ("Заполните поле 'Ф.И.О'  ", showToastCentered: false, timeoutMs: 1000);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (kod.Text)) {
            BTProgressHUD.ShowToast ("Заполните поле 'Код'  ", showToastCentered: false, timeoutMs: 1000);
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (tel.Text)) {
            BTProgressHUD.ShowToast ("Заполните поле 'Телефон' ", showToastCentered: false, timeoutMs: 1000);
        }
        else {
            using (var client = new WebClient ()) {

                street = ulitsa.Text;
                kvart = kvartira.Text;
                house = dom.Text;
                FIO = fio.Text;
                code = kod.Text;
                telephone = tel.Text;
                comment = coment.Text;
                var doc = new XmlDocument ();
                var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
                var filePath = Path.Combine (documents, "myFile.xml");//Path.Combine(documentsPath, "myFile.xml");
                doc.Load (filePath);

                var values = new NameValueCollection ();
                //values["Customer"].Replace("{FIO}", FIO);
                values ["Order"] = doc.OuterXml;

                values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{StreetName}", street.ToString ());
                values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{FlatName}", kvart);
                values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{HouseName}", house);
                values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{FIO}", FIO);
                values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{Code}", code);
                values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("{Phone}", telephone);
                values ["Order"] = values ["Order"].Replace ("..", comment);
                Console.WriteLine ("Proverka " + street + " " + FIO);
                Console.WriteLine (doc.OuterXml);

                values ["OrderText"] = "hello";
                doc.Save (filePath);
                Console.WriteLine (doc.OuterXml);
                var response = client.UploadValues ("http://91.246.122.43:1998/fas.asmx/AddOrder", values);
                Console.WriteLine ("---------------------Заказ отправлен на ФО-------------------------");
            }

        }

    };

}

}
```

Screenshot my design in Main.storyboard file:
[image]

I think my problem with segue, if I'm right how to use segue in code?
How I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

In designer don't draw your seque from the button to your next controller, simply draw it between controllers.
Then you can manually trigger it like this:

```
yourButton.TouchUpInside += (s, e) =>
{
    // do your checks here...

    // if everything is alright trigger your seque
    PerformSegue("YourSegue", this);
};
```